# Using a for loop in C# to calculate the average of a array of 10 numbers

Tags: c#, arrays

So i need to calculate the average of 10 numbers in a array with a for loop in C#.
I dont know how to do this since im a newbie in c#. Anyone kind enough to help me out?

this is the code i got so far:

```
namespace opdracht2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] array = new string[10] { "7", "8", "4", "6", "5,5", "7,5", "2", "3,3", "4.9", "8.9" };
            for (int i = 0, i <= array.Count, i++)
            {
                total += array[i]
            }

            float average = total / array.Count
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and paste the source code into the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and show what you have tried.

Comment: Indent code by four spaces to format it as code. Or use the formatting buttons.

Comment: Always proceed by breaking large problems down into small problems. Do you know how an average is computed?  An average is a sum followed by a division. So, now you have two problems. Do you know how to compute a sum?

Comment: yes i know how an average is computed. @EricLippert

Comment: Sorry guys for the lack of me not knowing how stackoverflow works correctly.

Comment: The way to use stack overflow is to have a *specific* question.  Your code is a mass of errors, and so it is hard to say what specifically you want help with. But I would start with syntax. You're missing two semicolons on statements, and the separator in a for loop is a semicolon, not a comma, so I would start there.

Comment: @EricLippert okay, will keep that in mind. and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;


class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] cijfers = new string[10] { "7", "8", "4", "6", "5.5", "7.5", "2", "3.3", "4.9", "8.9" };
            int i = 0;
            double sum=0;
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    sum+=double.Parse(cijfers[i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("The sum is: {0}",sum);
                }
                Console.Write("The average is: {0}",sum/10);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

The array variable here is defined as your array. Make sure you use `.Length`. This returns an integer that is the number of elements in your array. The average is the sum of all elements divided by the number of elements

```
float total = 0;
for(int i = 0, i < array.Length, i++) {
    total += array[i]
}

float average = total/array.Length
```

Comment: Obviously the array variable here is defined as your array. Make sure you use .Length. This returns an integer that is the number of elements in your array. The average is the sum of all elements divided by the number of elements.

Comment: Thanks for your help!